# Sending a message with PRAW but the receiving account does not ever get the message

Tags: python, reddit, praw

I'm trying for the first time using APIs with Python. I'm using PRAW. I've wrote a stupid easy script trying to send a message from one account to another. I'm prompted to login and enter the captcha, but then the receiving account does not ever get the message. What am I doing wrong? I need to get the foundations down to be able to progress onto a more complicated program that implements some logic and other methods.

```
import praw

r = praw.Reddit('PRAW related-question monitor by u/testpurposes v 1.0.') 
r.login() 
user = 'krumpqueen'
msg = 'Hello' 
r.user.send_message(user, msg)
```

Answer (score 0):

You're sending the message to yourself with subject 'krumpqueen'.

Try:

```
r.send_message(user, 'SOME SUBJECT', msg)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code appears to be correct.  The `r.user.send_message()` takes two arguments. The first is the user to receive the messages and the second is the actual message. So, your code is accurate. However, you shouldn't be receiving a captcha all the time. Try entering your reddit login info in the `r.login()` method. It should look something like `r.login('username', 'password')`. You might also see how much karma the account has. Your script may not be making it all the way through because of low karma.